# NaN when printing to console but typeof is number jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, nan, typeof

I'm implementing a timer, and trying to find out why I can't change the contents of my "min" input box when a number greater than 60 is entered in the input "sec" box. When I print the value of "mins", I get NaN, but when I print its type, I get that its a number. I'm just starting out with JavaScript, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $("#sec").change(function(){
        if($("#sec").val() >= 60){
            secs = parseInt( $("#sec").val() );
            console.log("secs is " + secs );

            if(secs < 0){
                alert("Please enter a valid time interval");
                $("#sec").val("");
                return;
            }

            mins = parseInt( $("#min").val() );
            console.log("mins is " + mins );
            console.log(typeof mins);
            hours = parseInt( $("#hour").val() );
            days = parseInt( $("#day").val() );

            secs = secs % 60;
            mins = mins + Math.floor(secs/60);//can be > 60
            console.log("mins is " + mins );
            console.log(typeof mins);
            hours += mins/60;
            days += hours/24;
            $("#min").val(mins);
            $("#hour").val(hours + mins/60);
            $("#day").val(days + hours/24);
        }
    });
});
```

html:

```
div class="left"></div>
    <div class="center">
        <h3> Please enter a time: </h3>
        <form class="form-inline">

            <div class="form-group col-xs-2">
                <input id="day" class="form-control input-sm input" type="number" value="" name="Days" placeholder="Days">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-2">
                <input id="hour" class="form-control input-sm input" type="number" value="" name="Days" placeholder="Hours">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-2">
                <input id="min" class="form-control input-sm input" type="number" value="" name="Days" placeholder="Minutes">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-2">
                <input id="sec" class="form-control input-sm input" type="number" value="" name="Days" placeholder="Seconds">
            </div>
```

Comment: The type of the constant `NaN` **is** "number".

Comment: why does everyone use parsetInt all the time? what's wrong with Number?

Comment: @dandavis: Indeed, or `+`. Using `parseInt` with a radix was important for a long time when engines extended JS to support octal, because the octal prefix was `0` and users typed in numbers with `0` at the beginning all the time, without wanting them to be octal. If the user types in `012`, they probably meant 12 decimal, not 10 decimal. So using `parseInt(str, 10)` became *de rigur*. ES5 made it clear engines really shouldn't do that and even forbade it in strict mode, which makes life a bit easier (the hex prefix is less of a problem; users are unlikely to type `0x12` and mean 12 decimal...)

Comment: technically, you should be doing your parseInt on the secs value **BEFORE** you do your `if()` test. essentially you've got `If (somestring > 60) { convert string to int }`.

Comment: @MarcB: that doesn't matter because the ">" operator will convert a string into a number to match 60...

Comment: @dandavis: true, but it LOOKS hinky, especially when `+` won't convert for you, but `>` does.

Comment: @MarcB: yeah, but this is JS, and all JS devs know that `+` is different than the others, unless you "use it twice", surely folks wouldn't over-coerce or ignore the simplicity of auto-coercion... </sarcasm>

Comment: @MarcB: *"...especially when + won't convert for you, but > does..."* Are you talking about the binary (two operand) `+` operator? Aka the "addition" operator? Because the unary `+` converts whenver `>` does...

Answer (score 10):

Despite the name "not a number," `typeof NaN` is `"number"`. Yes, really. :-) `NaN`, like `Infinity`, is of the number type. It's defined for numbers in [IEEE-754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) (the floating-point number format JavaScript and many other programming languages use; specifically, JavaScript uses what's now called the "[binary64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) subformat", aka "double-precision").

If you call `parseInt` on something it can't parse, it will return `NaN`. So for instance:

```
var n = parseInt("");
console.log(typeof n); // "number"
console.log(n);        // "NaN"
```

If you want to use `0` for `mins` (et. al.) when it's blank, you can do that with [JavaScript's curiously-powerful `||` operator](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html):

```
mins = parseInt( $("#min").val() ) || 0;
```

That will give you the number `parseInt` returned, or `0` if `parseInt` returned `0` or `NaN`.

---

Side notes:

1. If you're going to use `parseInt` for user-generated input parsing, you probably want to use its second argument, which tells it what number base to use (10, for decimal). E.g., `n = parseInt(str, 10)`. Otherwise, it tries to guess from the input (mostly, it treats strings starting with `0x` as hex).
2. `parseInt` will happily ignore extra characters after a number. For instance `str = "4 apples"; n = parseInt(str)` gives us `n = 4`. If you don't want that behavior, you might use `+` (`n = +str;`) or `Number` (`n = Number(str)`), both of which consider the *entire* string. But they both also accept `0x` at the beginning to mean hex, and don't support using a radix (number base).

Comment: @dandavis: `"object"` as in *object reference*, which `null` is. That's its primary purpose, in fact, to provide a means of representing "no object" when interacting with strongly-typed environments (like the DOM) that need an object type for null references.